# Sencha App does not find class in package

Tags: extjs, package, classpath, extensible

I packaged https://github.com/bmoeskau/Extensible:

```
sencha generate package -type code calendar
```

Then I added the line

```
package.framework=ext
```

to *.sencha/package/sencha.cfg* in the package.

And required the package in *app.json* of my app:

```
/**
 * The list of required packages (with optional versions; default is "latest").
 *
 * For example,
 *
 *      "requires": [
 *          "sencha-charts"
 *      ]
 */
"requires": [
    "calendar"
],
```

The package compiles successfully using `sencha package build`, but when I run `sencha app refresh` or `sencha app build` to build the app requiring the package, the following error occurs:

```
$ sencha app refresh
Sencha Cmd v5.1.3.61
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[ERR] C2008: Requirement had no matching files (Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel) -- /.../app/view/main/Main.js:20:442
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for /.../app/view/main/Main.js::ClassRequire::Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 4 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/me/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.3.61/plugins/ext/current/plugin.xml:403: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/.../.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/.../.sencha/app/init-impl.xml:303: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for /.../app/view/main/Main.js::ClassRequire::Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel
```

If I take the calendar example from the *examples* folder of Ext JS 5, and package it the same way, it works.

**Maybe it has something to do with the `Extensible` namespace? Am I missing something crucial?**

Answer (score 0):

I had an old package with name `"calendar"` in its package.json file in my packages directory. Even though the old package's folder name did not match its name, it was loaded first when I compiled the app. I renamed the package in its package.json file. Now it works and Extensible is found.